# How to create a raw data plot of a directional variable in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, direction, polar-coordinates

I have a dataset of wind directions and I am looking to create raw data plots as seen in the example below. I should mention that I know about rose diagrams and how to create them in Python. This is another way of looking at the data and is commonly brought up in texts about directional statistics.

[image: Raw circular data plot of 310 wind directions (source: Circular Statistics in R]

The plot is similar to a polar histogram, in that raw data is collected into continuous bins. But there are stacked individual dots for each data point instead of a bar.

I have found a solution on the mathematica stackexchange, but I have no experience with that language: [circular plot and circular histogram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31347/circular-plot-and-circular-histogram). The book I took the above image from also gives the R code for it, but I only know Python.

Below is the minimal code I have until now.

```
directions = np.random.randint(low=0, high=90, size=50)
# Setup plot
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)
ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.grid(False)

plt.show()
```

[image: Empty axes]

As you can see I have not made much progress. Again, I can find code for polar bar plots and histograms, but not for this type of plot in Python. Any hints in the right directions are welcome.

Comment: Plotting with `clip_on=False` will allow to plot outside the axes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest how do I deal with plotting the raw data points stacked?